# Typing a tuple of N numbers followed by a single string

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

Consider an array type like the following:

```
let example1: MyArray = ['John'],
    example2: MyArray = [4, 5, 1, 5, 'Eric'],
    example3: MyArray = [1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 'Joe'],
    ...
```

So one string in the end and an arbitrary count of numbers.

So far I can imagine a naive implementation of the `MyArray` type (which looks like the [*Death by a Thousand Overloads* problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-1-rc/)):

```
type MyArray = [string]
             | [number, string]
             | [number, number, string]
             | [number, number, number, string]
             | [number, number, number, number, string]
             ...
```

This is obviously suboptimal. Do better approaches exist?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Sure, but there’s a bunch of overhead doing that which may well be unnecessary. When properly typed, Typescript can handle this quite safely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can type this, though only in Typescript 4.2 or later: [Leading/Middle Rest Elements in Tuple Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types).

```
type MyArray = [...number[], string];

const example1: MyArray = ['John'],
      example2: MyArray = [4, 5, 1, 5, 'Eric'],
      example3: MyArray = [1, 5, 7, 3, 4, 5, 1, 'Joe'];
```

Prior to that, 3.0 introduced [Rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-elements-in-tuple-types), but at that time, rest elements were limited to the end of the tuple. So you could do `[string, ...number[]]`, but not `[...number[], string]`.

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it; you might want to link to the documentation for [leading/middle rest elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) introduced in TS4.2

Comment: Thank you! I messed around with the spread operator without luck, but it's clear to me now.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I had missed that the 3.0 version was limited to rest elements being the last part of the tuple.

Comment: @KRyan If you can think of a better title for my initial question, please feel free to suggest/change it

Comment: @KRyan just to clarify (now that I see the new title): the intention of the question was to solve the general problem - not specifically for numbers and strings.

Comment: @Mal Generally, questions work better when they’re specific—the solution to a specific problem is usually pretty clearly broadened to handle other cases.

Comment: @KRyan ok, thanks. I will carry that knowledge forward for future questions. I have previously used illustrative code examples to look for answers for underlying general problems.

Comment: @Mal There are, of course, limits to this; sometimes a specific example can become a red herring. (Though in my experience, specifying that it is only an example and you want the general answer doesn’t help all that much in preventing people getting stuck on it in such situations.) But as long as the example really is representative, it’s usually the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript allows for

```
type MyArray = [number, ...string[]]
const arr: MyArray = [12, 'wsd', 'qwdqwdqd', 'qwqdqdqdw'];
```

Unfortunately `type MyArray = [...string[], number]` is not allowed.
TS says `A rest element must be last in a tuple type.`

Comment: This was true until Typescript 4.2. Now, however, we are allowed to do this.